# Displaying a window with some information on android

Tags: java, android, service, window, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an app that displays some information in a window when incoming call arrives. To do it I have a broadcast receiver which starts the service, then the service gets needed information and opens the window using windowmanager object. I must keep the service running as long as the user doesn't close the window to prevent window closing unexpectedly. The problem is: the window gets closed at unexpected time because the system kills the service. I need that window to stay opened until user closes it. I need your suggestion what can I do to make that window stay opened as long as the user doesn't close it. And if there's a way without keeping the service running it would be awesome too. Maybe I should start a non full screen activity instead of window? Then the system wouldn't kill it so aggressively. Please suggest me something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have some code to show us?

Comment: I'm on my phone now so I don't have my code. But it has nothing to do with my code actually. It's such an ordinary situation when process gets killed because it only has a service which runs in a background. So I'm asking you to advice me what should I use instead of service - window combination. Maybe service - activity? This would put the process which hosts my service to a lower position of list of candidates the system wants to kill.